# Change Mesh face colors / materials at runtime

Tags: unity, mesh, materials, color, vertex

I'm trying to change the color/material of the faces on my object at runtime. My object has a default SpatialMappingWireframe to begin with:

[image]

And I'm trying to assign new colors on start like so:

```
void Start()
{
    Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

    Color[] colours = new Color[mesh.vertices.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        colours[i] = Color.red;
    }

    mesh.colors = colours;

    Debug.Log($"Colour Count: {colours.Length}");
}
```

I can see the debug line being output, but no changes to my scene:

[image]

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 1):

The default shader on a material does not support assigning new colours. Assigning a new shader to the material asset resolves the issue:

Quoting the a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55714190/985012):

1. in the `Project` view (Assets) do <kbd>right click</kbd> → `Create` → `Material`

   [image]
2. Give that material a name
3. For the `Shader` from the Dropdown menu find and select e.g. `Particles` → `Standard Unlit` (or if you want to receive lightning `Standard Surface`)

   [image]
4. Finally use this material for your object either by dragging it into the `MeshRenderer` → `material` or by simply dragging it onto the according object in the `Scene` view (the latter might not work if there is no mesh for that object yet)

---

Result:

[image]